# No result found in django rest framework in filtering option

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, filtering

Here is my model class :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    SKU    = models.IntegerField()
    price  = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField()
```

And the serializers is:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model  = Product
         fields = '__all__'
```

In my view I used this logic to filter Product by Status and Price.

```
   class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):

        class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = {
                'status': ['icontains'],
                'price': ['iexact', 'lte', 'gte'],
            }


    @api_view(['POST'])
    def productview(request):

        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer
        filterset_class = ProductFilter
        serializer = serializer_class()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

It gives the output like this

```
{
    "SKU": null,
    "price": null,
    "status": null
}
```

Now how can I get all the Product list(Index) according the **filter** ? Where I am giving the filter value as JSON like this.

```
{

    "price": 200,
    "status": 2
}
```

It will filter according to price== 200 and status==2.
And also, can I used **function based** view for this kind of filtering???

Comment: Try this (serializers.ModelSerializer) instead of (serializers.Serializer).

Answer (score 1):

I think this can't be done this way

I strongly recommend you integrating `django-filters` with `django-rest-framework` using **DRF**'s **Generic Views**.

Follow This [Official Guide](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html), for integrating it with **DRF**.